# Django: Pass arguments in View and display on the page

Tags: python, html, django

Say, I've got 2 views in `views.py`: `Fetching_information_view` and `Processing_view`.

In `Fetching_information_view` I am fetching information which I am displaying to the user in the tabular format on the `"home.html"` page. That's all okay.

Now, I get a CSV URL for each row as well. I don't want that when the user clicks on the CSV URL it should open the CSV; instead, when the user clicks on it then it should go to the `Processing_view` and it should be served on a different HTML page, say `"process.html"`.

CSV URL:

```
/some_bucket/some_csv_file.csv?AWSAccessKeyId=some_id&Expires=1234&Signature=some_signature
```

Desired URL:

```
http://example.com/process.html?file=some_bucket/some_csv_file.csv?AWSAccessKeyId=some_id&Expires=1234&Signature=some_signature
```

Now, how can I call `Processing_view` from the `Fetching_information_view` view and send the file information? It should process in the backend and display results on `process.html`.

This is the table I am showing on the homepage:

[image]

I've wrote sample code for views.py which I'm using:

```
def process_data(request):
    # what should come here?
    # Display in process.html


def home(request):
    some_data = SomeTable.objects.filter(user = request.user)
    args = {"some_data": some_data}
    # display as table on home.html, including URLs it is carrying
    return render(request, "home.html", args)
```

Comment: Assuming you have a urlpattern `process_view` for your `process_data` view, in your template "home.html" you can just put `href="{% url 'process_view' %}?id={{id}}"` to append the `id` of the object to your request.GET. In the process view you fetch the model with that id and the associated CSV url and file parameters.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works. Please write it as an answer, I will accept and upvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to expose the URL of your CSV files, then don't add it (and also don't expose the URL parameters) to the context of your `home` view and template.

So assuming you've created a urlpattern named `process_view` for your `process_data` view, in your *home.html* template you can just use `href="{{% url 'process_view' %}?id={{ id }}"` to append the `id` of the object to your request's URL parameters.

Then in the `process_data` view, you can get this `id` by `id = request.GET.get('id')`, fetch the model with this `id` and reconstruct the CSV url and file parameters.